# Setting column width to a percentage in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm having trouble with a table's behaviour in Firefox. I want a table consisting of two columns in the ratio 3:1. The first column includes 3 images in a second table which should resize to fit into the column.

In Chrome the images resize to fit into the first column, which is correctly set to 75%. They do this whether I specify a max-width or do not give them any size attributes. However, in Firefox, the images do not resize and instead the cell expands to be greater than 75%, meaning that the contents of the second column becomes squashed.

The structure of the code looks like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width: 100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align:top;width:75%;">
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <img src="image1.jpg" style="max-width:625px;" />
       </td>
       <td rowspan="2">
        <img src="image2.jpg" style="max-width:240px;" />
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <img src="image3.jpg" style="max-width:625px;" />
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td>
    Second column
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I adapt this code so that it works correctly in Firefox as well as in Chrome? I've read other related questions, but haven't been able to find a solution I can get to work.

P.S. Please no comments on how I shouldn't be using CSS like this. I have my reasons for not using a proper stylesheet while I'm playing around.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing the boat, why don't you simply assign a relative width to the image? A value of 100% will ensure the image resizes in tandem with its parent table cell:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width: 100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align:top;width:75%;">
    <img src="https://www.google.ca/images/srpr/logo11w.png" style="width:100%;" />
   </td>
   <td>
    Second column
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/j26Fm/

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the problem slightly to make it easier to explain, but then realised that this was an obvious solution. In fact I have several images within a second table. I have edited my original post to include this now. I may be able to set these columns to fixed percentages, but from what I've read the percentage widths can be a problem in firefox in general.

Comment: I've never found that to be true, though there may be edge cases. If you're having cross-browser issues, it's likely that there is ambiguity in your styling. Applying widths to your images and your table cells and see if that brings you any joy.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here I would say is `table-layout: fixed;`. It does require some additional rules but `table-layout` is what brings it all together.

Check out: http://codepen.io/pstenstrm/pen/kLKxz

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me, in IE, FF and Chrome.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; border: 0; cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 0;">
```

and

```
<tr valign="middle">
<td style="width: 25%;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%;"></td>
</tr>
```